# Can you ever get funded while you are in a different country?

Tags: postdocs

I'm not quite sure where this question fits, but is it possible in any field to get funded while you are abroad? As a post-doc is it possible to get funded say while you work remotely? I'm mainly talking in the EU.

This is purely hypothetical I'm just curious if this would ever be possible for any scientist. Maybe more possible for a theorist, someone who doesn't need a lab or equipment.

Comment: My son had a 3-year postdoctoral position in the U.S. that not only allowed but actually required him to spend a year abroad at a partner institution.

Comment: "but is it possible in any field to get funded while you are abroad?" There is a whole funding agency in Germany for this: https://www.daad.de/en/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Postdoctoral positions usually (always?)  come with a salary. So yes, for all academic disciplines, postdoctoral researchers are funded. The funds can come from your PI grant (in which case getting funds is not your problem), or from a university directly, or from a funding agency. The rules and regulations of providers vary widely: many large agencies make no restrictions based on nationality, but there are also many national agencies offering funding for candidates from EU or from a particular country only. Some funding streams are reserved for women or under-represented groups.

Distant work is not very usual in academia. Most universities will have strict rules saying that all full-time staff, postdocs included, must relocate to where the University is. Exceptions are possible in case of fieldwork or project work with partners overseas. However, if you want to get a postdoctoral position in country X and continue to live in your home in country Y, it may often become a dealbreaker.

Comment: I'm aware of quite a few cases where people at postdoc level have been officially employed in Country A, but spend a considerable amount of their time in Country B (typically because that's where their family is based). In some cases they have a secondary affiliation with an institution in Country B. However, this relies on the supervisor being willing to countenance such an arrangement. Typically supervisor and postdoc had already worked together; clearly it is necessary to establish trust first.

Comment: "Distant work is not very usual in academia": I've never had an academic work contract that prescribed relocation (I know such contracts for people working in hospitals, though, presumably including university hospitals) and I've done substantial amounts of academic work remotely (from home office in same town to living & working several 100 km away). Living in a different country would cause HR burocracy here in Germany to go from one heart attack to the next, though.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some examples where it might be possible:

You could probably get funding for for work at an EU university that required, say, archaeological work in Thailand. There are lots of similar situations. Some fields are like that.

Some scholars need access to library materials that are not portable. Ancient Maya stelae for example. You have to go there to read them. Manuscripts in monasteries, ...

But even a student of mathematics might need to go to say the US for a while to work with someone there. But the association would remain with the EU university.

People all over the world go to CERN for research, but maintain their affiliation and funding with the home university.

But, probably not, if the goal is just to see the world. Not on a post-doc, anyway. Likewise if the goal is just to avoid moving from where you currently are.